# Find CFG for the following language

Tags: context-free, pushdown-automata

I need to show that the following language is context free:

$$L = \{a^\ell b^n c^m | \ell, n, m \in \mathbb{N}^+ \wedge ((\ell \ge n) \vee (\ell \ge m))\}$$

Comment: Also [asked at Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3595432/find-cfg-for-the-following-language). Please do not cross-post questions, especially ones that already have answers on another site.

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: $L = L_1 \cup L_2$ for some $L_1$ and $L_2$ which are obviously context-free.

Hint 2:

> $L_1 = \{a^\ell b^n c^m | \ell, n, m \in \mathbb{N}^+ \wedge (\ell \ge n)\}$